# Bootstrap 3 multiline Navbar-brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 to create my website. I want  a nice multi-line navbar branding. I tried Brand nametag line

. But this is distorting the layout. Please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 0):

**Deep Singhal** Hi there.
Is this what you are looking to do when you want **multi-line navbar branding**?

You could override the Bootstrap `class`of **navbar-brand** like this...

```
.navbar-brand {
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And then add a `div`that will wrap the `a` links for the multi-lines that you want like this...

```
<div class="navbar-brand ">  
    <a href="#">Project name</a><br>
    <a href="#">Project name</a><br>
    <a href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/859b4rp3/)** of this for you to view.
If you want the text to be larger etc then make the navbar taller as well.
Hope this helps.

[image]